# How to pass my Firebase data from didSelectItemAt to ultimately cellForRowAt (w/o storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift5

I am able to pull my own data from database and display it to my collectionViewCells... this is the label I have on my **CustomCell** (*UICollectionViewCell*) to refer to my Category model (i've only added one label here to simplify what i'm asking :))

```
func generateCell(_ category: Category) {

    nameLabel.text = category.name

}
```

and this is what I have on my main UICollectionViewController

```
///empty array to collect data
var categoryArray: [Category] = []
```

//

```
private func loadCategories() {
    downloadCategoriesFromFireBase { (allCategories) in
        //            print("we have \(allCategories.count)")
        self.categoryArray = allCategories
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    loadCategories()
}
```

//CellForItemAt

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.generateCell(categoryArray[indexPath.row])

    return cell
}
```

this works like a charm and displays all my cells correctly with all data.

its on `didSelectItemAt` that lies the **problem**

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let category = categoryArray[indexPath.item]

    let newVC = SomeTableViewController()

    newVC.category?.name = category.name

     navigationController?.pushViewController(newVC, animated: true)

}
```

based on what you can see on didSelectItemAt and after I placed this `var category: Category?` onto my SomeTableViewController() the categories types still return `nil` when im trying to print the category name on my viewDidLoad()

How can I pass my category info to the tableViewController after I've selected a certain cell without Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the entire category object instead of passing the property name to the non initialized newVC category object (which is why your newVC category object is equal to nil).

So, essentially, instead of this:

```
newVC.category?.name = category.name
```

Do this:

```
newVC.category = category
```

An optional chain (in your case category?.name) will only succeed, if the optionals inside that chain contain a value. In your case, category is still nil since it wasn't assigned a value at the time you were trying to assign a name to it.

To illustrate what you are doing with an example:

```
var category: Category! /* category is nil since it's not initialized */
category?.name = name  /* category is still nil, so assigning a value to its property fails */
```